# How to set the default float position, e.g., set it to be H?

Tags: floats, positioning

Is there a way to set the default position option for floats?

I want all float to by default to use the option `H`. Then I only need to set position parameter for those floats that I do not want to use `H`.

Comment: If your default preference is that the item (a figure or table, right?) should *not* float, then don't use LaTeX's float-related mechanisms. Simply load the `caption` package and use its macros `\captionof` to generate the caption. By the way, be prepared for substandard layouts if you never (or hardly ever) want tables and figures to float.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`float`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/float) package already offers a command `\floatplacement` to do this:

```
\usepackage{float}
\floatplacement{figure}{H}
\floatplacement{table}{H}
```

Answer (score 4):

Put the following in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
  \providecommand*\floatlocation[2]{\@namedef{fps@#1}{#2}}
\makeatother
\floatlocation{figure}{H} % for figures
\floatlocation{table}{H}  % for tables
```